# Brother MFC-8840DN and OS X Catalina

Tags: catalina

I have a Brother MFC-8840DN network printer/scanner/fax machine that I've been using with my Mac since Snow Leopard.

With Catalina, Apple is dropping support for 32-bit applications, which would include the driver and the scanner/fax application (both from Brother).

Will I be able to get my printer to work with Catalina?

Comment: No.  Have you [contacted Brother for updated drivers](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/os/macintosh.html)?

Comment: I have.  They have said that they are not going to release updated (i.e. 64-bit) drivers.  I asked if they would be willing to release the source so I could update them, but there are unwilling to do so.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading, the existing printer instances (CUPS and BR-Script3) worked as they had in OS X Mavericks (and earlier).  Both suffered from the inability to remove the job from the queue after printing, but this isn't related to Catalina.

I created a new printer instance, using the `Brother MFC-8840D BR-Script3` driver and everything works as expected, including clearing the queue.

Note: OS X does not recognize the device's scanner feature, so I cannot use Preview to `Import from scanner...`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a scanner or printer issue, one has to update the printer-scanner's software to 64-bit.
I got the updater and installed it on my Mac first
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc8890dw_all&os=10060&dlid=dlf104915_000&flang=4&type3=318

Then I connected the printer to my Mac and ran the updater.